# Understanding average noise variance in Wiener Filter

Tags: math, image-processing, variance

I was reading about this Wiener Filter algorithm:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/wiener2.html

... and I do not understand the ν squared value (aka: average noise variance).

So given this dataset: 150, 175, 200, 100, 225, 175, 75, 100, 150

We have a mean value of 150 and variance of 2500.

How do I calculate the average noise variance?  I don't really understand it.

I am trying to apply this to a local adaptive algorithm and the data above represents a 3x3 matrix around the center value, 225.

**Update:**

The example data above is a 3x3 matrix window that is just part of a larger image.  If SergGr is correct, do I create a 3x3 window around every pixel... summing the variances and then dividing by the number of pixels in the image?  So if my overall image was just 3x3 for example, I would create 9 total windows, one for each pixel?

Comment: I believe that if 3x3 data is all you have - you are out of luck. If you actually have a big image and this 3x3 is just a small subset, then I _think_ that the sentence "_If the noise variance is not given, wiener2 uses the average of all the local estimated variances._" means that the estimate for `ν` is the mean of all estimates for `σ` calculated for all MxN windows.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  So I have to iterate through the entire image once, creating a 3x3 matrix window for each pixel, getting the variance for each matrix, and then find the mean value?  That seems pretty expensive because it almost forces you to do two loops calculating the variance, once to get the average and once to apply the filter.  Thank you.

Comment: The `wiener2` function can return an estimate of this parameter, you don’t need to provide it if you dont know it. In general, if you add noise to the image, that noise has a variance. This is the value that you would fill in there. If you don’t know the noise strength, it can be estimate, this is what the  `wiener2` function does if you don’t provide the noise variance.

Comment: Thanks Cris, I am essentially creating my own wiener2.  I just need to understand how to calculate the average noise variance.

Comment: You need to estimate it. You don't know what the noise is, so you can't compute its variance either. One common trick I remember from long ago is to look at the power spectrum (of the whole image, not a window), and find the power at high frequencies. Usually the signal power falls logarithmically with the frequency, but the noise power stays constant across all frequencies (assuming white noise). (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) The other option is to 1) find strong edges, 2) create a mask far away from all strong edges, 3) compute the local mean filtered input, 4) subtract the mean from the input, and 5) compute the mean square of that result within the mask (i.e. far away from edges).

Comment: Btw: tag my name (`@CrisLuengo`) in your comment to ping me, otherwise I won't see your replies.